# Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'database_user' at heroku remote connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

iam trying to connect my heroku app with remote database by following method:
I have a variable DATABSE_URL in enviornments variables on heroku that is

```
mysql2://database_user:password@server_name:port/database_name
```

After pushing my rails app to heroku master when i `run heroku run rake db:migrate`

I got this error

> Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user
>   'database_user'@'ec1-54-137-144-44.compute
>   -4.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES)

I am unable to figure out what exactly is happening, i have already created 1 database with database_name on phpmyadmin.
**I have set all permissions to this database user**

My database.yml file:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: database__name
  username: db_user
  password: password
  host: host
  port: 2082
```

Please help

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solved it ?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your remote MySQL server is not allowing all IP addresses to be connected. For me, the solution was adding % allow (0.0.0.0) to my allowslist. So, if you have a restriction like this on you Remote MySQL server, configure it to allow all connection requests from all IP addresses.

[image]